# Any suggestions for a more direct PROPER text format - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I'm creating a workbook that will automate the formatting process for customer service department at the non-profit I work for. They will copy/paste data into the workbook, run the procedures, then copy/paste out and import into their database.

One of the processes is taking fields such as first and last name, etc, and putting them into the "proper" or "title" case format. The code below is currently how I'm executing this process but I can't help but think that there has to be a more direct way. I've searched but to no avail.

Please lend me your wisdom!

```
'Proper Format
Range("AS1:BA" & myLR).FormulaR1C1 = "=PROPER(RC[-28])"
Range("BB1:BB" & myLR).FormulaR1C1 = "=PROPER(RC[-26])"

Range("Q2:Y" & myLR) = Range("AS2:BA" & myLR).Value
Range("AB2:AB" & myLR) = Range("BB2:BB" & myLR).Value

Columns("AS:BB").Delete Shift:= xlToRight
```

Comment: this is pretty good as is. You could load the ranges into an array, manipulate the array and rewrite the array to the range, but its probably not necessary with what you have.

Comment: As @ScottHoltzman any other answer will require loops and depending on the data it will be slower than your method.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you do want to loop through each cell, use this, it's pretty quick...

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim MyLr As Long, rng As Range, c As Range

    MyLr = Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("Q2:Y" & MyLr)

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        c = StrConv(c, vbProperCase)
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your response. I'll check it out!